# How to bind rows with integer and character

Tags: r, bind

I would like to bind all my files together, I used this code for other files already and it was working well, now I have a problem with integer and character. 
Here is the code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)

read_pvt_file2 <- function(filename){
  print(filename)
  subject_id <- substr(basename(filename), 1, 8)
  data <- read_csv(filename)
  colnames(data) <- c("Nb", "RawTime",  "reSYS",    "reDIA",    "Physiocal",     
  "Time",   "Score")

  data$Subject <- subject_id
  data
  }


all_csv_files_in_dir <- function(dir){
   list.files(dir, pattern = "\\.csv$", full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)
 }


 df_all <- bind_rows(map(all_csv_files_in_dir("F:/Study/Dawn simulation 
light/Analysis/Hemodynamics/Labview Done BP files"), read_pvt_file2))
```

But here is the error that I got:

```
Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) : 
  Column `Score` can't be converted from integer to character
```

Do you know how to deal with this error? 
Thank you.

Comment: you can specify the column type in `read_csv` using the `col_types` option

Comment: I tried to add [col_types="numeric"] after the colnames(data)=.... but it doesn't work....

Comment: The most probable cause is that `Score` in one or more files contains NA integers. See [this issue on Github](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2584) for discussion and a fix.

Comment: Voting to close as not having a [MCVE]. The error depends on whatever is in the file on the questioner's F: drive. We can spend all night guessing at what the error might be, but why should we need to do so?